# How to get distinct on specific column w.r.t inserting order using sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

here im having a sql table as shown below

```
---------------------------
   id | element | parent_id
---------------------------     
    1  |   La   |    1
    2  |   Ce   |    1
    3  |   Pr   |    1
    4  |   Nd   |    1
    5  |   Sm   |    1
    6  |   La   |    1
    7  |   Ce   |    1
    8  |   Pr   |    1
    9  |   Nd   |    1
   10  |   Sm   |    1
   11  |   La   |    2
   12  |   Ce   |    2
   13  |   Pr   |    2
   14  |   Nd   |    2
   15  |   Sm   |    2
-------------------
```

i want the output like below having only element with inserted order w.r.t parent_id

```
-------------
    element 
------------     
    La
    Ce
    Pr
    Nd
    Sm
------------
```

for this i wrote the code as

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT distinct(element) from mytable where 
parent_id=1) A ORDER BY NEWID()
```

with this i got the output as

---

```
    element 
------------     
    La
    Ce
    Nd
    sm
    pr
------------
```

it is not which i want,please help me how to get element with inserted order

Comment: If your `id` is an auto incremental value, you could (probably) sort on that. If it isn't, and you haven't yourself build a method to track insertion order, there is no way to do what you want. Sql server doesn't (automatically) keep track of order of insertion.

Comment: Also, `DISTINCT` is not a function, so remove the parentheses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY`instead of `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT element
FROM mytable 
WHERE parent_id=1
GROUP BY element  
ORDER BY MIN(id)
```